# How to get unique identifier from attached UsbDevice in android

Tags: android, kotlin, usb

I'm working on an android app where the app needs to connect to multiple USB devices at once and with every connected device, there is a UI controller which controls the connected device. The goal is to reconnect a USB device to the same controller to which it was connected, once the user plugs out and plugs back in the USB device.

I'm mapping `UsbDevice.getDeviceId()` to the controller and am expecting the `UsbDevice.getDeviceId()` to return the same Id for the same device when connected in the same port.

But every time the same USB device is disconnected and connected, `UsbDevice.getDeviceId()` returns a different Id resulting in the app not being able to map to the already connected controller. For example, when a USB device was connected, `UsbDevice.getDeviceId()` returns 1010. But if the same device is disconnected and connected again, it will return 1011.

Can somebody help me figure out what could be a unique identifier for a USB device that can be used to achieve the above-mentioned functionality? Thanks